# Small number out of DOUBLE range

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-insert, create-table

I created a table on a mariaDB with the following definition. Note the longitude and latitude fields.

```
Create Table geo_data (
    geo_data_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    place_id int NOT NULL,
    longitude DOUBLE(18,18) SIGNED,
    latitude DOUBLE(18,18) SIGNED,
    Primary Key (geo_data_id),
    Foreign Key (place_id) References place (place_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

When I try to insert data into the `geo_data` table using

```
Insert into geo_data (place_id, longitude, latitude) Values (1, 1.2, 3.4);
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Error: ER_WARN_DATA_OUT_OF_RANGE: Out of range value for column 'longitude' at row 1
```

I guess I am missing something here, since I don't believe `1.2` could in any way be out of range of a `Double(18,18)`. So what on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column is defined as `DOUBLE(18,18)`. The first number is the *scale* (the total number of digits in the whole number, including decimals); the second is the `precision` (the number of decimal positions).

Giving the same value to both the scale and precision means that your value cannot be greater than `1` (all 18 digits are decimals).

You want to decrease the precision to something smaller in order to leave room for non-decimal digits, like: `DOUBLE(18, 6)`, which gives you 12 non-decimal positions.

Comment: A thanks, I think I misread / misinterpreted the documentation